# use sum function with negative variable in sas

Tags: sas, sum, sas-macro

I'm new to sas and not able to figure what this statement does in the data step

```
sum(column1, -(col2 * col3))
```

Comment: That is not a statement.  It might be part of a statement, but even then it is missing a closing right parenthesis.

Comment: Depends on where it is. That could be in SQL, data step or IML. And it could have different meanings in some of those depending on other things. So it depends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SUM` function returns the sum of the non-missing argument values.

Adding a negative summand expression to `column1` is the same as subtracting the expression from `column1`.  The expression `(col2*col3)` itself could be missing, negative, 0, or positive.

The maths analog would be

```
result = column1 + -(col2*col3), being the same as
result = column1 - col2*col3
```